# Does days or number of times used have priority in Appirater?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appirater

With Appirater, it allows us developers to ask the user to rate the app. There are two different settings:

```
static double _daysUntilPrompt = 15;
static NSInteger _usesUntilPrompt = 10;
```

My question is simple, do 15 days have to go by and 10 uses have to both be YES to have the alert come up? Or do they have a priority type of logic, meaning if one happens before the other, the alert will come up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have to happen before it will come up

Answer (score 1):

You can see the logic for yourself on [line 180 of Appirater.m](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/blob/master/Appirater.m#L180):

```
- (BOOL)ratingConditionsHaveBeenMet {
    if (_debug)
        return YES;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSDate *dateOfFirstLaunch = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[userDefaults doubleForKey:kAppiraterFirstUseDate]];
    NSTimeInterval timeSinceFirstLaunch = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfFirstLaunch];
    NSTimeInterval timeUntilRate = 60 * 60 * 24 * _daysUntilPrompt;
    if (timeSinceFirstLaunch < timeUntilRate)
        return NO;

    // check if the app has been used enough
    int useCount = [userDefaults integerForKey:kAppiraterUseCount];
    if (useCount <= _usesUntilPrompt)
        return NO;
```

Both conditions need to be met.